# CoreBluetooth iOS API in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

Does CoreBluetooth iOS API available for iOS project of Xamarin.Forms? I know it is available for Xamarin.iOS. Is there any way to make use of the same for Xamarin.Forms? Have anyone tried this before?

Comment: You can  refer this link https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/tree/master/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench/Plugins/Sphero

Comment: use DependencyService to expose platform. specific APIs to your common Forms code